# What context should I pass to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

What context should I pass when using SQLite?

I got error :  **Fragment TimeTableFragment{f07e75e} not attached to a context**.

My app works like :
DeleteDialog Ok button-> deleteColum ,
TimeTableFragment.sendData(Context context)  *sendData is draw data in layout

```
DeleteDialog.java

public class DeleteDialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

private Context mContext;
TimeTableFragment timeTableFragment;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_delete_dialog, container, false);

    mContext=this.getActivity();

...

timeTableFragment = new TimeTableFragment();
    ok_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(editText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "과목명을 입력해 주세요", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                dbHelper.deleteColum(editText.getText().toString());
                timeTableFragment.sendData(mContext);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }

        }
    });
```

TimeTableFragment.java

```
private Context mContext;

public void sendData(Context context) {


    //Log.d("tag", " 컨텍스트" + getContext()==null? "yes": "no");
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.onCreate(db);
    String date = "", start = "", end = "", title = "", color = "";

    ArrayList<SubjectItem> timetable_data;
    timetable_data = dbHelper.getDataTimetable(); //get data from sql
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");

    int resID = 0;
    int mok;
    Date a, b;
    long diff, min;
    View view = getView();

    for (int i = 0; i < timetable_data.size(); i++) {
        date = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_date();
        start = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_start();
        end = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_end();
        title = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_title();
        color = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_color();

        if (date.substring(0, 2).equals("Th")) {
            date = "h";
            Log.d("ㄹㄹ","목요일 : " +date);
        }
        date = date.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1);
        Log.d("ㄹㄹ","바깥의 데이터 : " +date);
        start = start.replace(":", "");
        end = end.replace(":", "");


        try {
            a = sf.parse(start);
            b = sf.parse(end);
            diff = b.getTime() - a.getTime();
            min = (diff / (1000 * 60));
            mok = (int) min / 30;

            Log.d(TAG,"title " +title + " start :  " + start +","+ a.getTime()+ " / end : " +  end+","+b.getTime() +   "   date : " + date);

            for (int k = 0; k < mok; k++) {

                if (mok != 1) {

                    if (end.substring(2, 4).equals("30")) {
                        end = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(end) - 30);
                        if (end.length() == 3) end = "0" + end;
                        Log.d(TAG, " 그리기 title :  " +title );
                        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(date + end, "id", mContext.getPackageName());
                        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(resID);
                        textView.setText(title);
                        paintTimetable(textView,color);

                    } else {
                        end = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(end) - 70);
                        if (end.length() == 3) end = "0" + end;
                        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(date + end, "id", mContext.getPackageName());
                        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(resID);
                        textView.setText(title);
                        paintTimetable(textView,color);
                        Log.d(TAG, " 그리기 title :  "  +title);
                    }
                } else {
                    resID = getResources().getIdentifier(date + start, "id", mContext.getPackageName());
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(resID);
                    textView.setText(title);
                    paintTimetable(textView,color);

                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {

        mContext=getContext();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

My DBHelper.java

```
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

...

public void deleteColum(String name)
{
    String DELETE = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TIMETABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_TITLE + "='" + name + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(DELETE);
    Log.d("dd", "sql deleted  :  " + name);

}
```

and my logCat :

```
ragment TimeTableFragment{f07e75e} not attached to a context.
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:696)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:760)
    at com.example.a13.timetable4.TimeTableFragment.sendData(TimeTableFragment.java:138)
    at com.example.a13.timetable4.DeleteDialog$1.onClick(DeleteDialog.java:52)
```

Comment: Try to call `sendData` inside your `onAttach` method in `TimeTableFragment` and pass your context as parameter there.

Comment: @HendraWD Thanks for you answer, but It caused NullPointerException error  : NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 mContext = this.getContext();
```

Instead of:

```
 mContext = this.getActivity();
```

Comment: Thank you! Context error is solved! But still sendData method doesn't work immediately. It draws when I restart my app. Do you know the reason?